# Create a route with coordinates Leaflet OSRM

Tags: leaflet, osrm, leaflet-routing-machine

With OSRM and Leaflet, I need to create a route.

What the user do :

- select (multiple or single) any itinerary (polyline) displayed on map
- when they are selected the user can create the route

How can i create a route from coordinates of they polylines ?

With OSRM we need to add waypoints, but my coordinates are not waypoints and they are numerous!

Should I reduce the array of coords? But I need to be sure, that the route use the correct itinerary :/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far and can you share your code?

Comment: Hey @Fearcoder Thank you, 

I have tried to : 

- add my coordinates as waypoints
- get route from L.Routing.Control and change its coordinates
- try to set waypoints start and end with my coordinates [0] & [length-1] 

and other things like that, but not working at all, i think waypoint cant be to many like that 
i need to set coordinate tos the route but i dont know how 
now im installing in local the OSRM project to test with node-osrm, but i dont know how that works x )

sorry for my english